# Customise Edit Button for ContentTools

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, content-management-system, wysiwyg

I am having a hard time to understand how I could change the appearance and/or position of the edit (Ignition) button in [ContentTools](http://getcontenttools.com/) (a wysiwyg editor).

I found out that I can use `editor.start();` and `editor.stop();` to trigger the editing of the page and I would like to map these function to my own buttons but I cannot get rid of the default button.

The documentation and tutorials on their website did not help me enough to understand this.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no shortage of editors available. If the features you need aren't documented or available, find another one that is

Comment: I need a very simple, free lightweight wysiwyg editor that also allows image uploads. I've used CKEditor but I don't like it too much since I'm using Laravel as a framework, and to upload an image you need a filemanager and it is just too much just for being able to edit 2 textareas and upload an image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 ways I recommend doing this, the simplest option is to hide the ignition button (as it's called) like so ([reference SASS](https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/blob/master/src/styles/ui/_ignition.scss)):

```
.ct-ignition {
    display: none;
}
```

If you would prefer to remove the button from the DOM entirely then you could unmount the button from the UI like so ([reference CoffeeScript](https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/blob/master/src/scripts/ui/ignition.coffee)):

```
// Once the Editor has been initialized
ContentTools.EditorApp.get()._ignition.unmount();
```

My advice would be to use CSS to hide the ignition and to trigger events against it to call functionality manually via your custom button, like so:

```
var editor = ContentTools.EditorApp.get();

// Starting the editor manually
editor._ignition.trigger('start');

// Stoping the editor manually (save)
editor._iginition.trigger('stop', true);

// Stoping the editor manually (cancel)
editor._iginition.trigger('stop', false);
```

It may be useful to review these questions asked on the the projects github issue list also:

- https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/issues/77
- https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/issues/78

Comment: Thank you! that helped a lot!

Comment: I can't get the following to work;
var editor = ContentTools.EditorApp.get();
// Starting the editor manually
//editor._ignition.trigger('start');

But I can get this to work;
var editor = ContentTools.EditorApp.get();
editor.start()

Did the API change?